# What does the cmake variable Torch_DIR do? How do I find out what directory to hint for find_package(Torch)?

Tags: cmake, libtorch

In an official [tutorial showing CMake for a project to depend on libtorch](https://pytorch.org/cppdocs/installing.html), we have this CMakeLists.txt:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.0 FATAL_ERROR)
project(example-app)

find_package(Torch REQUIRED)
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} ${TORCH_CXX_FLAGS}")

add_executable(example-app example-app.cpp)
target_link_libraries(example-app "${TORCH_LIBRARIES}")
set_property(TARGET example-app PROPERTY CXX_STANDARD 14)

# The following code block is suggested to be used on Windows.
# According to https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/issues/25457,
# the DLLs need to be copied to avoid memory errors.
if (MSVC)
  file(GLOB TORCH_DLLS "${TORCH_INSTALL_PREFIX}/lib/*.dll")
  add_custom_command(TARGET example-app
                     POST_BUILD
                     COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E copy_if_different
                     ${TORCH_DLLS}
                     $<TARGET_FILE_DIR:example-app>)
endif (MSVC)
```

Now, the documentation is old and does not work for many people, as referenced by this github issue:https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/issues/12449

The solution that was suggested (and works for me) was to set an additional variable:

```
set(Torch_DIR "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/external/libtorch/share/cmake/Torch")
```

In this directory there are some `.cmake` files with comments at the top that says "Finds the torch library".

What I don't understand is why this variable has to be set in addition to the call to `cmake -DCMAKE_PREFIX_PATH=/absolute/path/to/libtorch ..`, which is what the libtorch documentation instructs you to do.

I thought the [`CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/variable/CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH.html) is the variable set in order to use `find_package()`

My question is: Why do you need both for it to work?

Comment: well, what are you passing in your `-DCMAKE_PREFIX_PATH=/absolute/path/to/libtorch`? If you're passing the equivalent of your `${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/external/libtorch`, I'm pretty sure that would be the problem, solvable by changing it to the equivalent of `${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/external/libtorch/share/cmake/Torch`. See also [the docs for `find_package`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/find_package.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PyTorch apparently provides utilities for getting what the CMake prefix path to use is: run the following `python -c 'import torch;print(torch.utils.cmake_prefix_path)'`. Whatever you get from that is what you should either put in your [`CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/variable/CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH.html), or set as `Torch_DIR`. See also [this thread on the CMake Discourse](https://discourse.cmake.org/t/cmake-for-pytorch-c/5210?u=starball).

PyTorch uses find-package config scripts (not find module scripts) (see also [its `cmake/TorchConfig.cmake.in` file](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/blob/main/cmake/TorchConfig.cmake.in)). You shouldn't need to both put a find-package script's containing directory in `CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH` and in `<PACKAGE-NAME>_DIR`. Only one is necessary (and you can choose which one you want to use).

For how `CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH` comes into play, see step 2 in https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/find_package.html#config-mode-search-procedure. Note though that `CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH` has implications/uses also for `find_program`, `find_library`, `find_file`, and `find_path`.

The `<PACKAGE-NAME>_DIR` variable is actually a CMake cache variable that's supposed to store the result of running the find search procedure, so setting it directly is just short-circuiting that search and providing the result right away (at least- that's my understanding, which might be wrong). From the docs:

> Config mode search attempts to locate a configuration file provided by the package to be found. A cache entry called `<PackageName>_DIR` is created to hold the directory containing the file.

Comment: Thank you, this provides some clarity, and I will certainly read the linked resources. 

I did see that `import` trick.  However, I'm not using python at the moment, I'm writing a pure c++ application. I'm doing so exactly so I can learn about CMake in a more "real world" way than what the official tutorial provides. It's been tough, but I think I'm getting there. Thanks again.

Comment: As a quick follow-up, I wanted to confirm that you do only have to set one of the two. I went with CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH, as that seems canonical instead of the 'short circuit' you mentioned.